# STL Sort with no deal breaker

Tags: sorting, stl

Our game engine uses STL `sort` for sorting a whole range of different objects using the template `sort` function. As I understand the requirements for the comparison logic is that you have to write it on the basis that it may internally do a reverse sort ( ie reverse the pairing eg. from `(a,b)` to `(b,a)` ).

So typically my compare functions looks like this:

```
bool CompareSubGroupReqsByDescendingFillPriority::operator()
    ( const ScenSubGroupReq&  lhs, 
      const ScenSubGroupReq&  rhs ) const
{
    if( lhs.mFillPriority > rhs.mFillPriority ) return true;
    else if( lhs.mFillPriority < rhs.mFillPriority ) return false;
    else return lhs.mForceGroup->ObjectID() > rhs.mForceGroup->ObjectID();
}
```

I refer to the "else" statement as the "deal breaker" - ie. it must be able to resolve a case where both lhs and rhs are the same. I typically use the object ID where we are sorting persistent objects.

My question is how can you create a deal breaker when you are sorting non-persistent objects that are simple data types (eg shorts)?

Here is the example I am wrestling with:

```
bool
ComparePhaseLineIndexesByAscendingValue::operator() ( const short  lhs, 
                                                      const short  rhs ) const
{
    if( lhs < rhs ) return true;
    else if( lhs > rhs ) return false;
    else
    {
      // should never be here as no two phase lines should have the same index
      FPAssert( false );
      return false;
    }
}
```

Trouble is I have been testing this and found a valid case where where I can have two phase lines with the same index. I don't care which of the entries with the same value ends up first.

What would you advise?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the issue.  Your program is crashing at the assert?

Comment: STL comparators should return **false** for objects that equal. Use `lhs<rhs` - this is what STL algorithms except from you.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the sort function takes the less than operator. What you are trying to do seems to have something to do with making sure that even equal objects are returned in a specific order. Generally you would just do

```
bool
ComparePhaseLineIndexesByAscendingValue::operator() (   const short  lhs, 
                                                        const short  rhs ) const
{
    return lhs < rhs;
}
```

Though generally a comparison function isn't required for builtin types (I think it's any type with a < operator specified).